# Writing OpenCl Kernels in Python using PyOpenCl

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

When I write code in PyOpenCl, do I still need to write the kernels in C, or can I write them somehow in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you still need to write the kernels in C.

It really is not much of a pain to deal with.  And if you want a bit more abstraction, you can create a domain specific language with Python that maps to parts of C kernels.

The reason C is required for writing kernels is because OpenCL exists to create extremely performant applications.  In order to make the most out of a GPU, you need to control the exact on-chip operations that the application does (such as bitwise operations), and how the application allocates the GPU's memory spaces (global, shared, and local).  C is a great language for having that sort of control.